# Как рассчитать длину прыжка в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Создаю игру, прыжки в длину (пока что). И как мне просчитать дальность прыжка по X, после того как нажал на кнопку Jump? А когда приземляется bool isGrounded = true (хотя это вряд ли надо)

Comment: Во первых, вы задаете очень непонятный вопрос, так как неизвестно что у вас уже написано, и собственно в чем возникает проблема. Во вторых прежде чем создавать игру нужно проработать "движок" вашей игры, а вернее физику. И вот тут то и начинается, надо учитывать вес вашей прыгающей модели, возможности и пр. А в вопросе этого не оговорено, соответственно сам вопрос слишком общий, и вам необходимо дописать подробности.

Comment: Дело в том, что в скрипте кроме разгона и прыжка ничего нет. Я хочу реализовать такую вещь: когда нажимаю Button (OnClickJump) начало просчитывать расстояние по X до приземления, и это расстояние как-то возвести в метры (сантиметры). Прошу хотя бы без написания скрипта подсказать, какими методами это реализовать.

Comment: разгон, он же ускорение, рассчитывается исходя из силы и массы по закону Ньютона.

Comment: На самом деле это плоховатая идея для твоего случая. Лучше не рассчитывать это расстояние заранее. Просто используй у объекта поля вроде скорость, масса, ускорении и прочее и просто исходя из них обновляй положение и параметры, соответственно. Воть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут чистая физика, за класс эдак 7-й/8-й.

Буквально, чтобы посчитать длину прыжка, тебе надо знать скорость по горизонтали, и время полёта тела, ну и умножаешь скорость по горизонтали на время полёта, получаешь такую нужную длину прыжка.

В именно данном этом случае дело обстоит так:

У тебя есть 2 пути здесь:   Топорный и более-менее человеческий

Топорный: задаёшь сам скорость и время полёта, умножаешь, бам, вот твоё расстояние

Человеческий: у тебя есть масса, и импульс, который получает тело при прыжке, через косинус и синус раскладываешь их на вертикальную и горизонтальную составляющие, горизонтальная -- считается чрез косинус, это скорость полёта и будет константой всегда, вертикальная -- через синус, уменьшается по таймеру на значение гравитации (обычно ~10), и когда нижняя часть твоего тела имеет координату земли, тогда и  bool isGrounded = true

Фишка в том зачем тебе считать эту длину? ты написал

> Создаю игру, прыжки в длину (пока что).

То есть потом ты их будешь делать только в высоту, без перемещения по сторонам?)

Раз у тебя игра с прыжками, я бы порекомендовал брать некий тикрейт с определённой задержкой по времени, таймер в Unity, и по нажатию на твою кнопку прыжка добавлять телу импульс (скорость) и дальше по формуле ньютона, если задержка достаточно мала, то можно будет высчитывать полностью все координаты твоего тела при помощи векторной алгебры (но это уже чисто отсебятина и вода)

Я надеюсь что я помог тебе разобраться в этом вопросе хоть сколько-то ;)

Comment: а если прыжок в среду (например в воду)? Это физика 9-го класса, и тут хочшь не хочешь, а вспоминай законы Ньютона.